# Deleting files from SharePoint online, why does this always produce Error 403?

Tags: rest, axios, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to delete a file from a folder in a document library in SharePoint online via REST services. I'm already doing several other CRU(D)-Operations on files and lists for this solution, all working fine, except for the (D)elete.

I have tried several methods of accessing the file, e.g. `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`, `GetFileById (=UniqueID)`, `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` and then using `/Files`. I have also tried going about it via ListItems, i.e. using `/lists/getByTitle('MyTitle')/items(ID)`. I am a Site Collection Administrator for this site. I am getting a X-RequestDigest, which is working fine for all other operations.
The solution is written in TypeScript & React and is using axios for http-Requests.

```
var deleteConfig = {
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "IF-MATCH": "*",
          "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
          "X-RequestDigest": (document.querySelector("#__REQUESTDIGEST") as HTMLInputElement).value
        }
      }

axios.post(this.props.baseUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/MySite/DocLib/Test5.txt')/recycle()", deleteConfig)
        .then(response => {
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(ex => {
          if (ex.response.status === 403) {
            alert("Access Denied!");
            console.log(ex);
          } else {
            alert("Error deleting file (" + ex.response.status + "): " + ex);
            console.log(ex);
          }
          reject();
        });
```

Any deletion (with or without "/recycle()") results in an error 403 with message "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.". I'm unable to see why this call would fail, when all other posts, merges and puts are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, using JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
    bindButtonClick();
    });

    function bindButtonClick() {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
    deleteDocument();
    });
    }

    function deleteDocument() {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var webRelUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + webRelUrl + "/DocLib/" + "Test5.txt" + "')";

    $.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
    "IF-MATCH": "*"
    },
    success: onQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
    });
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
    $("#divResults").html("Document successfully deleted!");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("Error!");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually working inside a script editor webpart. I will try to work my way backwards to make my call from typescript work in a similar way.